# How to always show all PR conversations in GitHub?

Tags: github

When looking at a GitHub pull request with lots of conversations, some of them will be hidden behind a "Load more…" link:

[image: hidden conversations screenshot]

As someone giving and receiving feedback, this is terrible UX:

- In a big page it is easy to miss, because it doesn't stand out much.
- I can't search for a particular conversation, because it's not part of the page markup.
- I might have to hunt down this link more than once to show all the conversations - it seems to only load 20 conversations at a time.

I found a [JavaScript workaround](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1190#issuecomment-367607027), but having to install this and remember to click it every time I load a pull request is tedious. **Is it possible to permanently disabling this feature for my account?**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a solution, but it might be a workaround:

1. In a GitHub PR, change the tab from "Conversation" to "Files changed".
2. Open the dropdown called "Conversations" which lists all of them. Unresolved conversations are listed first.

[image: GitHub PR Conversations Dropdown Example]

User [ldog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883807/disable-hidden-conversations-in-github-pull-requests/69135692#comment131937717_69135692) explains some limitations with this in the comments below:

> Unfortunately this only works if the comments are in sync with the latest commit or the commits that you are currently looking at, if you wanted to see all comments across all commits, this doesn't work. For example, when clicking on a comment that no longer exists due to code changes in a commit this does nothing.

I would prefer to find the same solution the OP is seeking, but I wanted to share this for anyone else landing here with the same issue in case someone finds it helpful.

Also, I'm cross-posting this information in [a related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883807/disable-hidden-conversations-in-github-pull-requests/69135692#69135692).